# Utilizing A Secondary IP On A NIC In A Windows Cluster

Tags: networking, ip, cluster, subnet, windows-cluster

**RELEVANT INFORMATION**

I have a windows cluster with 3 nodes in it...

- Node1
- Node2
- Node3

I have 4 NICs on each node...

- NIC1_Host
- NIC2_Virtuals
- NIC3_Cluster_HB
- NIC4_Live_Migration

This is the config for Node2's NICs...

- NIC1_Host

  1. IP: 10.71.1.21 - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.128 - Gateway: 10.71.1.1
  2. IP: 10.71.1.213 - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240 - Gateway: N/A
- NIC2_Virtuals

  1. N/A
- NIC3_Cluster_HB

  1. IP: 10.71.1.130 - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248 - Gateway: N/A
- NIC4_Live_Migration

  1. IP: 10.71.1.138 - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248 - Gateway: N/A

So at this point in my Windows cluster I can see three networks...

- ClusterHB (10.71.1.130) [Network: 10.71.1.128/29]
- LAN (10.71.1.21, 10.71.1.213) [Network: 10.71.1.0/25]
- LiveMigration (10.71.1.138) [Network: 10.71.1.136/29]

Now that all of that is configured I move into my clustered app service that I created called "MyAppService".  Under the general tab I have the list of IP addresses.  There are a few things to note here...

1. I can only have one IP address added to this list.
2. When I edit or add an IP I can only choose the network 10.71.1.0/25 which is good and bad.

---

**THE QUESTION**

So my question is, how can I incorporate my new network in the mix?  From what I understand these cluster networks are auto added.  But for some reason it's only adding 1 cluster network per network card and in my case I need it to add 2 for the NIC1_Host NIC.  Why is windows clustering not adding a network for the  10.71.1.208/28 network?  In the end I expect the following to be shown under the "Networks" section of the cluster...

- ClusterHB (10.71.1.130) [Network: 10.71.1.128/29]
- LAN (10.71.1.21) [Network: 10.71.1.0/25]
- iSCSI (10.71.1.213) [Network: 10.71.1.208/28]
- LiveMigration (10.71.1.138) [Network: 10.71.1.136/29]

Comment: Whilst I've been unable to find any evidence of it (and I don't have a cluster available that I can test on currently), I suspect that you can only use the primary address of the NIC in a cluster - I believe any secondary addresses will be ignored. Like I say, I've been unable to find any evidence of this, but equally, I haven't been able to find any scenario where two IP addresses are present on one NIC in a cluster. Is there anyway that you could instead set up another VIP on the 10.71.1.0/25 network and then route traffic to it from the 10.71.1.208/28 network?

Comment: I was looking into trying to add a virtual nic to my cluster nodes but I ran into some issues on 2008 r2.  I was going to add a new legacy device via hardware manager (network adaptor) then use Microsoft->Loopback as the adaptor.  That gives me a new network card to use but how can I get it to piggyback off the NIC1_Host adaptor?  Currently I guess it's just a NIC connected to...  itself?...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The use of multiple ips on a single network card can usually only work when they are a clustered resource with the failover cluster manager. In each nic you add a single network ip address with or without a gateway in the operating system. You can add a cluster resource of type ip address to setup a access point for the resource. I use this for things like a sql server instance has an ip address in addition to the client access point so it can be backed up as a virtual point on a network for backup when the resource moves between the cluster hosts. When you go to the create an ip address screen you will only see the logical networks from the network cards as a subnet possible to use.

The Failover Clustering network driver detects networks on the system by their logical subnet. It is not recommended to assign more than one network adapter per subnet, including IPV6 Link local, as only one card would be used by Cluster and the other ignored.

Reference:
[Windows Clustering Configuration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2014/02/20/configuring-windows-failover-cluster-networks.aspx)

Comment: I don't mean to be stupid ...  or rude but I can't seems to follow what you are saying here.  I have a NIC called "NIC1_Host" (as stated above) with two IPs.  This is the part that trips me up when reading your answer "You can add a cluster resource of type ip address to setup a access point for the resource.".  Could you elaborate on that part by chance?  - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  The best way I have found is to add an IP address from a different subnet is via the command line.  For example, create a new cluster resource of type IP Address (assume the resource default name is "New IP Address").  Then, to assign it IP address 10.71.1.213, run the following:

C:\> Cluster.exe res "New IP Address" /priv address=10.71.1.213